# How to limit calendar table on a page level in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have my calendar table that goes beyond today's date. That's what I need for the report.

But on one of the pages on my report I need calendar table only on or before today's date.

I tried to filter calendar table but seems like there is no way it can be dynamically filtered as of `TODAY()`

[image]

Is any way to limit calendar table until particular date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated column to flag your desired values using the following pseudo DAX:

```
IsBeforeToday :=
SWITCH ( TRUE (), 'Calendar'[Date] <= NOW (), 1, 0 )
```

Then, use this as a visual level filter in your report, setting the value to one.

Comment: It won't let me use `'Calendar'[Date]` table. I guess I need a single value

Comment: @Oleg this would need to be a calculated column in your calendar table

Comment: Nice!  Thank you !

Comment: sure no problem